Yarn Build Error: TS2305: Module '"web-vitals"' has no exported member 'ReportHandler'
I'm using Yarn as part of an intro to React Testing course through Udemy.
I am getting this error when executing yarn build:
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.22
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TS2305: Module '"web-vitals"' has no exported member 'ReportHandler'.
  > 1 | import { ReportHandler } from 'web-vitals';
      |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2 |
    3 | const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry?: ReportHandler) => {   
    4 |   if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {      


error Command failed with exit code 1.

The error is coming from a file that came with the sample application.
ReportHandler really isn't in the module section under web-vitals.  I tried re-adding web-vitals, but no joy.  I tried add ReportHandler, but I could not figure out a command that would find a repo for it.
Here is my package.json file
{
  "name": "react-testings2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.3.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "web-vitals": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}


web-vital change syntax after release newer version
this link helped me github issue
import { MetricType } from "web-vitals";
 
const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry?: (metric: MetricType) => void) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    import("web-vitals").then(({ onCLS, onINP, onFCP, onLCP, onTTFB }) => 
{
       onCLS(onPerfEntry);
       onINP(onPerfEntry);
       onFCP(onPerfEntry);
       onLCP(onPerfEntry);
       onTTFB(onPerfEntry);
     });
   }
 };

 export default reportWebVitals;


I learned that ReportHandler being deprecated. I ran create react app in a new folder, did NOT run yarn update as the instructor called for,moved my work over, and now everything runs fine.

Alternatively, you can update to the new version by changing your code in reportWebVitals.ts (or .js) file to use MetricType instead of the deprecated ReportHandler class as per this response.
import { ReportCallback } from "web-vitals";

const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry?: ReportCallback) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    import("web-vitals").then(({ onCLS, onINP, onFCP, onLCP, onTTFB }) => {
      onCLS(onPerfEntry);
      onINP(onPerfEntry);
      onFCP(onPerfEntry);
      onLCP(onPerfEntry);
      onTTFB(onPerfEntry);
    });
  }
};

export default reportWebVitals;

